# Python test cases fails in Google Foobar challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I learnt python for Data Science and recently Google invited me to take up the foobar challenge. The first question is pretty simple and I am able to get the desired output on my local machine, but not even a single test case passes in foobar. Please find the question below and the code.

*Given two almost identical lists of worker IDs x and y where one of the lists contains an additional ID, write a function solution(x, y) that compares the lists and returns the additional ID.*

*For example, given the lists x = [13, 5, 6, 2, 5] and y = [5, 2, 5, 13], the function solution(x, y) would return 6 because the list x contains the integer 6 and the list y doesn't. Given the lists x = [14, 27, 1, 4, 2, 50, 3, 1] and y = [2, 4, -4, 3, 1, 1, 14, 27, 50], the function solution(x, y) would return -4 because the list y contains the integer -4 and the list x doesn't.*

Below was the first code I wrote, which worked on my local machine, but failed all test cases on foobar.

```
def solution(x,y):
    set1=set(x)
    set2=set(y)
    answer=list(set1^set2)
    for i in answer:
        print(i)
```

Upon researching, I could understand that the way foobar calls this function is : solution.solution(x,y)
So I tried defining a class and the method within the class, which again works fine on my local machine, but as usual fails all test cases in foobar. Please find the different variants of my code which I tried. All the below codes work fine with the visible test cases of foobar on my local machine, but fails the same on foobar.

**Please help me. I just have 2 days left to solve this question.**

```
class solution:
    
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        
    def solution(x,y):
        set1=set(x)
        set2=set(y)
        answer=list(set1^set2)
        for i in answer:
            print(i)
```

```
class solution:
     
    def solution(x,y):
        set1=set(x)
        set2=set(y)
        answer=list(set1^set2)
        for i in answer:
            print(i)
```

```
class solution:
    @staticmethod
    def solution(x,y):
        set1=set(x)
        set2=set(y)
        answer=list(set1^set2)
        for i in answer:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

> the function solution(x, y) would return 6

Reading the instructions *very* carefully is usually a good starting point for this sort of issue. :) I don't see a `return` statement in your code - there is a big difference between printing and returning!

...

`return i` will solve a lot of your problems

Comment: Thank you Ben for answering.
Missed to mention, I tried return as well many times, even that doesn't work with foobar. 
Also, return (i) only returns one element and closes the function. Print(i) prints all the elements of the answer list.

Comment: Doesn't the challenge specify that there is only *one* additional ID? If so then you would never need to return a list. The instructions also use the word "return" explicitly, so printing is never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works.

```
def solution(x, y):
    set1 = set(x)
    set2 = set(y)
    unique = list(set1 ^ set2)
    return unique[0]
```